# From Field locked on Email form in dynamic CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

"From" field on Email form is locked.I can't understand why it is behaving like this.Because we haven't locked it on form and we also doesn't use any script for that.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by locked?

Comment: @vanita why would you want to change the from of an email?

Comment: @keerz its our requirement for a workflow.Email will be send from a queue.So we need to change the from."From" field behaving same in form and workflow.

Comment: @james Locked means we can select any other user or queue in from field.It only show logged in user in from.[As you can see in image][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MbHEr.png

Comment: So its read-only then (locked is something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to be an issue with Update 1 for CRM 2016. The only solution I found was to:

1. Create a new Solution, find the Email entity and add only the *From* field to the Solution.
2. Export the Solution, extract it and open the customizations.xml file.
3. Find the `<LookupTypes />` tag and replace it with:

> ```
> <LookupTypes>               
> <LookupType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">8</LookupType>
> <LookupType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">2020</LookupType>
> </LookupTypes>
> ```

4. Save changes, zip back the Solution folder and import it back to your CRM organization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution solves this issue, but you should remark that this is an unsupported customization, though.